# Pass multiple php arrays in ajax request response

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I'm trying to pass multiple arrays in Ajax request response(get), but unfortunately I'm not able to get it done.

This is my php code I'm willing to send into Ajax request response:

```
echo json_encode($catdata);
echo json_encode($productdata);
echo json_encode($data);
```

My js ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "../api/test.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var j=0;
        $.each(data,function(l,item){
            var arrlength = data[l].countdest;
            while(j<=arrlength)
            {
                (function(j)
                {
                    $('#catbtn').click(function(){
                        if(j<=arrlength)
                        {
                            $('#resultdiv').append('<p name="destinationid">'+data[j].destinationid+' '+data[j].name+'</p>');
                            var a;
                            for(a=0;a<4;a++)
                            {
                                alert(a);
                            }
                            //$('#resultdiv').append('<input type="checkbox" name="destinationid" value="'+data[j].destinationid+'" '+data[j].name+'/>');
                            j++;
                            if(j==arrlength)
                            {
                                $('#catbtn').hide();
                                $('#submit').show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                (j));
                i
            }
        });
        //alert(arrlength);
    },
});
```

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var formData = {
                    array1 : yourArray1,
                    array2 : yourArray2,
                    array3 : yourArray3
                };
  $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "trial2.php",
       data: formData,
       success: function(result) {
           console.debug(result);
       },
```

Edited , now check

Comment: This gives 'data' not defined :'(

Comment: Console says:

[array[15],array[64],array[4]]

and the arrays passed are:

$newarray = json_encode(array($catdata, $productdata, $data));

How to read the data in js?

Comment: received those array in your php file like $data = $_post['array1']

Answer (score 0):

Try to send them all in one array:

```
echo json_encode(array($catdata, $productdata, $data));
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to these array contents in javascript? It would be really helpfull.

Comment: The object created from this json will be an array with three elements. Each one will be one of arrays

Comment: Console says: [array[15],array[64],array[4]] and the arrays passed are: $newarray = json_encode(array($catdata, $productdata, $data)); 
How to read the data in js?

Comment: OK, so $catdata is in data[0], $productdata  is in  data[1] and $data  is in data[2]. In other words data is an array of arrays (data is the object given by jquery)